# Primefaces filedownload in Datatable celleditor not working

Tags: file, primefaces, datatable, download, tablecelleditor

I have a Datatable in Primefaces with a celleditor to upload and download files. 
The file upload is working. 
The file download doesn't work, it only reloads the page.
When I put the download Button direct under the p:column, the download is working. (So the download button is visible in edit mode)

What is wrong, any ideas?

Here is my code (simplified):

```
<p:column headerText="Header">
  <!-- Download Button at this position works -->
  <p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
      <p:commandButton id="download" value="Download" ajax="false">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.downloadFile}" />
      </p:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
      <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadFile}" label="upload" mode="advanced" auto="true" process="@this" />
    </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

And the managed bean:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;


public StreamedContent getDownloadFile() {
    final InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/test.png");
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/png", "test.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a fix, but I had the same issue in my app and solved it by removing the cell Editor component, and styling the remaining components to appear side by side (display: inline-block) to provide something that looks nice.